# can't insert into database (webservice)

Tags: php, sql, web-services

I am creating a web service which will be called from an android app. Actually I am trying to do an insert into my database but i can't figure out why it is not working. Here is my code, with some tests I have made in order to find the bug :

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

    /* here is the original code that I commented in order to do my tests
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $mdp = $_POST["mdp"];
    $nom = $_POST["nom"];
    $prenom = $_POST["prenom"];
    $dateNaissance = $_POST["dateNaissance"];
    */
    $mail = "test@mail.fr";
    $mdp = "test";
    $nom = "test";
    $prenom = "test";
    $dateNaissance = "2000/01/01";

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO utilisateur (mail, mdp, nom, prenom, dateNaissance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $mail, $mdp, $nom, $prenom, $dateNaissance);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM utilisateur";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $final = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);

    print_r($final);
?>
```

The `SELECT` request returns me the row I have in my `utilisateur` table so I suppose it's not a problem of connection.

Moreover, `mysqli_stmt_execute($statement)` returns 1... So if i'm not wrong it's supposed to mean that my request worked ? Anyway, nothing is inserted.

I'm hosting my database with 000webhost, don't know if this will help... I'm starting developing so everything is not crystal clear.

Hope that I was understandable and that you'll enlighten me!

Comment: How do you check if something is inserted?

Comment: Could it be the date variable $dateNaissance which is formated in none mysql date style ? I assume it's trying to put it into a date column..

Comment: Try this after the execute printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($statement));

Comment: if your `dateNaissance` column is `DATE` then your `2000/01/01` will fail. MySQL uses `YYYY-mm-dd` as its format. You should post what your db schema is for all this. If your column is varchar, then that's not a good idea, yet you should make sure that all columns are long enough to accomodate the data; the question is unclear.

Comment: @u_mulder i go to my phpMyAdmin interface

Comment: @JasonK returns me " Error: . " ?

Comment: @chickenchilli yes i'm trying to put it in a date column... but when i echo my query, and then copy/paste it in phpMyAdmin, it works perfectly !

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm really sorry, i'm new to stackoverflow and was waiting for mails since I checked the "send mail when answered"... Well, to answer your question even if you left, if in phpMyAdmin i enter the query "INSERT INTO UTILISATEUR(mail, mdp, nom, prenom, dateNaissance) VALUES ("test", "test", "test", "test", "2000/01/01")" it works perfectly...

Comment: Can you try without the date insertion in your code ? Just to make sure that's not an issue. Other thing could be rights. So is the user on phpMyadmin the same as in your script ? Or long story short do you have INSERT granted on the user in your script ?

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. Here is my 'utilisateur' table script : CREATE TABLE `utilisateur` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `mdp` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateNaissance` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE `utilisateur`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`);

ALTER TABLE `utilisateur`
  MODIFY `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: check to see if your POSTs aren't empty `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @chickenchilli I tried without the date insertion and it doesn't work either. I just verified the privileges via phpMyAdmin and everything is checked....

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just checked, they contain data

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong : everything was working really well... But i was connecting to the wrong database. Indeed I began my project in localhost and then used 000webhost hosting. I got confused since it was written "server : localhost" in the two phpMyAdmin interfaces and also because I had the exact same table in the two databases.

Thanks for the answers that still made me learn.

Answer (score 0):

The query causes this error

```
Error: Field 'idUser' doesn't have a default value.
```

You will need to fix your table. Make it an InnoDB table.

```
CREATE TABLE `utilisateur` (
  `idUser` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mail` VARCHAR(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `mdp` VARCHAR(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom` VARCHAR(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `prenom` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateNaissance` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```